# How can I use the mouse to draw a filled arc/wedge of a disc?

Tags: unity, c#

Instead the mouse for testing I tried to use StartCoroutine to set the speed the circle will be drawn. The speed does change according to the seconds to wait but it also showing the radius line from the center:

[image: Circle]

And

[image: Circle]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public int segments = 50;

    public bool circle = true;
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public float xradius = 15;
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public float yradius = 15;
    LineRenderer line;

    void Start()
    {
        line = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        line.positionCount = (segments + 1);
        line.useWorldSpace = false;

        StartCoroutine(CreatePoints());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //CreatePoints();
    }

    IEnumerator CreatePoints()
    {
        if (circle == true)
            yradius = xradius;

        float x;
        float z;

        float change = 2 * (float)Math.PI / segments;
        float angle = change;

        for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * xradius;
            z = Mathf.Cos(angle) * yradius;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, 0, z));

            angle += change;
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to use the mouse without dragging, only by moving, to draw a circle around the object (instead of drawing the circle automatically). So if I move the mouse only some of the way it will draw only part of the circle.

And I want to make the circle filled.

The circle will be drawn with a fixed radius around the selected object but with the mouse. The mouse movement will decide how much of the circle will be drawn. The idea is to make smooth mouse movement and drawing.

The idea is to use the mouse to draw something like the Handles.DrawSolidArc: an Arc but in the game view not the scene view.

Something like that:

[image: Arc]

Comment: I'm 99% sure something called a line renderer can't really render filled polygons. Try dynamic meshes

Comment: I'm 100% sure the LineRenderer does not draw filled shapes. I've removed the "With LineRenderer" from the question title, since that constraint would make this unanswerable.